# PHP Variable of Stripe API

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I need help with PHP and the Stripe API.

```
        $stripe->accountLinks->create([
            'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
            'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
        ]);
```

That gives me back an answer like this:

```
{
  "object": "account_link",
  "created": 1606772720,
  "expires_at": 1606773020,
  "url": "https://connect.stripe.com/setup/s/QaVzgu7GNGFP"
}
```

I need help to know how to display the "url" in a variable in PHP.

I've tried to do this but it doesn't work:

```
        $link = $stripe->accountLinks->create([
            'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
            'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($link);
        $links = $data->url;
```

If someone knows what I can do it would help me a lot. Thanks :)

EDIT:
The var_dump returns this:

```
object(Stripe\AccountLink)#127 (4) { ["object"]=> string(12) "account_link" ["created"]=> int(1606856512) ["expires_at"]=> int(1606856812) ["url"]=> string(47) "https://connect.stripe.com/setup/c/vD45DxCl0hZQ" }
```

But I just need url string

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data);` and add that output to your question. If the JSON response looks exactly like you've posted, then your code looks correct. Also, where and how did you determine that `$links` doesn't contain what you expect? And are you doing something with that variable before you checked it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is too vague. Do you get an error? And I seconds Magnus' remark, that posted JSON can be decoded just fine. If there's more to that response, please add the whole string.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if I make $data = var_dump($link); I get the json, but I need to get the "url" in a PHP variable

Comment: The code you posted should work with the JSON you posted. Can you share the dump, without omitting anything from it?

Comment: Please pay attention to details. I didn't ask you for `var_dump($link);`, I asked for `var_dump($data);` which you should call _after_ your json_decode(). Also, `var_dump()` doesn't return anything. Just place it on it's own line in your code.

Comment: Something else is wrong https://3v4l.org/krZmd You said "display" maybe `echo`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that returns null

Comment: Did you place `var_dump($data);` right _after_ the line `$data = json_decode($link);`? Can you please edit the question to include that as well? And also include how yo uchecked that `$links` doesn't contain what you expect. I suspect that you might be doing something else after this code.

Comment: I bet that `$links = $data->url;` does give you the URL but that you're either doing something funky with that variable after the posted code or trying and output it in some strange way. But until we can see that code as well, who knows.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I edited with the var_dump code

Comment: Too jumbled.  `json_decode` will not give you `object(Stripe\AccountLink)`

Comment: Making this: ```$url = var_dump($link->url);``` it returns me this:  ```string(47) "https://connect.stripe.com/setup/c/b6DMVNwcATM```

Comment: Can you dump $link before json decoding?  I suspect you might be using some client library in which `$link` is already an object (and not a json string) which has a `url` property you can access using `$link->url;`

Comment: I made it work, I added a new answer with the solution, thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to `json_decode` the resulting account link object. All you need to do is access the URL property on the object returned by Stripe. For example:

```
$link = $stripe->accountLinks->create([
    'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
    'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
    'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
    'type' => 'account_onboarding',
]);

$url = $link->url;

echo $url;
```

You can use the `$url` variable in a template or to perform any other server-side logic. The structure of the returned account link object can be referenced here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/object

Answer (score -1):

I've made it work by doing this:

```
                        $link = $stripe->accountLinks->create(
                          [
                            'account' => 'acct_1HtKYcRm0s9vfiNs',
                            'refresh_url' => 'https://example.com/reauth',
                            'return_url' => 'https://example.com/return',
                            'type' => 'account_onboarding',
                          ]
                        );

                        $var_url = var_export($link->url, true);
                        $good_url = str_replace("'", "", $var_url);
```

Now when I echo "good_url" I get the full url successfully.

Thank you all very much, really, you have helped me a lot.